# Can I access the "secondary this" from an inner class?

Tags: java, nested, inner-classes, derived-class

I have basic classes

```
abstract class Unit {
    Unit target;
    abstract class UnitAI {/*...*/}
}
```

From these, I have derived

```
class Infantry extends Unit {
    class InfantryAI extends UnitAI {/*...*/}
}
```

**Can the class `InfantryAI` somehow get the *secondary*(*implicit*) `this` that is used for accessing the members of it's surrounding class `Infantry`?**

Specifically, it needs to determine if its surrounding class `Infantry` is being targetted by its target, like this:

```
if (/*secondary_this.*/target.target == secondary_this)
```

or, generally, by another `Unit`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The refference to the outer class; I guess I should have used the term *outer* `this`, instead of *secondary* `this`.

Comment: _Enclosing instance_ would also work.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks, I'm a little unclear on the proper terminology... I searched for "access from inner class", but only found questions related to member access, not the object refference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the *outer* `this` by prepending the classname:

```
Infantry.this.target; //"this" of the Infantry class from inside InfantryAI
Unit.this.target; //"this" of the Unit class from inside UnitAI
```

This doesn't work with `static` nested classes though as they don't belong to a instance of the outer class.